# My Facebook account "likes" pages on its own – what can I do?

Tags: spam-prevention, facebook

For a few months I have been noticing that my Facebook account is liking random pages on its own, even when I remove them, they keep getting added (liked).

- Why is this happening?
- Is my account compromised?
- What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 13):

First, remove permissions from all the applications under Account Settings -> Applications.

If you haven't changed your password, do it now.  Also change the password to any email accounts associated with your Facebook account.

Start with a clean slate here and see how that goes.

Comment: And if you use the same password on any other site, change it there too -- to a different password.

Comment: @RandyOrrison: Very good point and a critical addition.

Comment: is there any confirmation that the account/computer is hijacked? It's 2019 today